# Selecting a TreeTableRow does not change background color

Tags: java, css, javafx

I tried to implement different coloring of my `TreeTableView` since there are `DummyElements` that should be separated visually from the other elements. Since they still are editable and stuff, there also has to be a certain style when they are selected. I tried the follownig:

```
 .tree-table-row-cell:selected .text {
       -fx-fill: white ;
}

.tree-table-row-cell .tree-table-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: grey
}

.tree-table-cell .text {
       -fx-fill: black ;
}
.tree-table-cell {
        -fx-background-color: gainsboro
}
```

> I dont know why, but the text color changes but the backgroundcolor
>   doesnt.  Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay as always, when I post something here on SO, i find the answer shortly after, but since this is not very intuitive I wanted to share the solution.

```
.tree-table-row-cell:selected .text {
       -fx-fill: white ;
}

.tree-table-row-cell:selected .tree-table-cell {
    -fx-background-color: grey
}

.tree-table-cell .text {
       -fx-fill: black ;
}
.tree-table-cell {
        -fx-background-color: gainsboro
}
```

You want the to change the `fx-background-color` property of the `tree-table-cell` of the `tree-table-row-cell:selected` pseudo class. 
You **DONT** want to change the `fx-background-color` property of the `tree-table-cell:selected` pseudo class since it doest no exist (afaik).

The thing is, that naming of all classes is a bit weird in javaFX...

Comment: Why is it not intuitive? You are presumably in "row selection mode" (the default), so it is the rows that are selected, not the cells. If you [enable cell selection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TableSelectionModel.html#setCellSelectionEnabled-boolean-) then the cells would be the nodes that were selected.

Comment: I might have tested shifting the ":seleceted" pseudoclass one tier higher earlier if it wasnt called tree-table-row-cell. What is it? A row or a cell? For me its not intuitve to have two mutually exclusive words in the class identifier. 

The lack of in-depth tutorials is kind of a problem as well, I admit. I saw hundrets of "how to change the color of a button" tutorials, but few to no tutorials with detailed explainations of the styling concept or the javaFX architecture. Sidenote: I didnt even know there were two different selction modes.

Comment: It's an instance of [`TreeTableRow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableRow.html), which is a subclass of [`Cell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html), so in a very real sense it is both a row and a cell (it's the `Cell` that is responsible for displaying the entire row).

Comment: Well... that makes sense then. I'm kinda new to JavaFX. Don't be to harsh on me, please. Is there a more in-depth tutorial somewhere on th internet?

Comment: I just learned by reading the standard [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) (which isn't very good), and the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/overview-summary.html#JavaFX). Plus, I guess, looking at code on this site, some good GitHub repos ([try this one](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea)), and looking at the source code for JavaFX itself and some libraries such as [RichTextFX](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX) and [afterburner](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/).